# Exponential maps on a level set

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Thanks in advance for any help or a link for me to read up.

Consider a known differentiable function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$, where $x_i$ are real numbers and $(x_1,\ldots,x_d) \in\Bbb R^d$ i.e. are points in the $d$ dimensional Euclidean space. Given the zero level-set $D = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_d)\in\Bbb R^d\, |\, f(x_1,\ldots, x_d) = 0\}$, let's assume that $D$ forms a $d-1$-dimensional manifold and that $D$ is not empty.

Starting from a point on $D$, $p \in D$, how do I compute the exponential map? At every such point $p$, what I know are:

1. normal vectors $\mathbf n(p)$, computed from $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and then normalize.
2. tangent space $T_p(D)$, computed using $\mathbf v(p)\cdot\mathbf n(p) = 0$ for all $\mathbf v\in T_p(D)$.
3. I can sample a random tangent vector $\mathbf v \in T_p(D)$ and try to construct the exponential map from here.

**In sum, my question is**: how to compute the exponential map and trace out a geodesic in $D$?

Thank you.

Comment: The answer is essentially the same as for any hypersurface. Probably the easiest approach is to use the implicit function theorem to write $D$ locally as a graph $x_d = h(x_1, \dots, x_{d-1})$ and use the characterization of geodesics on a graph. Basically, a parameterized curve is a constant speed geodesic if and only if its acceleration, as a curve in Euclidean space, is everywhere normal to the hypersurface.